# lodash throttle nor debounce is working in Angular 5 project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash, throttling

I am trying to use lodash throttle and debounce functions in angular 5 project, however it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Behavior is that the function parameter that is passed to either of the functions is never executed.

For example with throttle, I am importing it using the following approach:

```
import throttle = require('lodash/throttle');
```

Then, inside any method, I have the following:

```
throttle(this.testFunction, 100);
```

I have also tried:

```
throttle(() => {
          this.testFunction();
        }, 1000);
```

testFunction is just the following:

```
  public testFunction() {
    console.log('test function!@!!@!');
  }
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

`throttle` does not call a function. It returns a new function, that, when called, ensures that the true function you passed to `throttle` is called, at maximum, once every x time:

So, if you do:

```
throttle(func, 100);
```

Nothing happens. You must do:

```
let throttledFunc = throttle(func, 100);
```

And you must call `throttledFunc` instead of `func`. `throttledFunc` will check that you haven't called the function in at least 100 ms

So, if you do:

```
setInterval(throttledFunc, 50); // execute every 50 ms.
```

`func` will be only called every 100 ms, not every 50.

Comment: I didn't need a setInterval, so I just used `throttledFunc.call()`.